# show post whose comment have more likes than the post

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend, django-database

In django i want to show some posts on homepage with 1 or 2 comments.

I want only those post to be shown whose comments have more likes than the post's likes.

```
class Post:
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,...)
    ...

class Comment:
    ...
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,...)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,...)
    ...
```

Comment: So you take the sum of the likes of the comments? The average? What if a user likes two comments of a post, does that count as two, or one?

Comment: i just want to compare post likes and comment likes. if post likes < comment likes then i will show them to users. If a user likes two different comment, likes on each comment will be counted for comparision .

Answer (score 2):

We can work with an annotation to count the number of likes of the `Post` and its comments:

```
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef, Subquery

comment_likes = Comment.likes.through.objects.filter(
    comment__post=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by().values('comment__post').annotate(
    c=Count('pk')
).values('c')

Post.objects.alias(
    num_likes=Count('likes')
).filter(
    num_likes__lt=Subquery(comment_likes)
)
```

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT post.id
FROM post LEFT
OUTER JOIN post_likes ON post.id = post_likes.post_id
GROUP BY post.id HAVING COUNT(post_likes.customuser_id) < (
    SELECT COUNT(U0.id) AS c
    FROM comment_likes U0
    INNER JOIN comment U1 ON U0.comment_id = U1.id
    WHERE U1.post_id = post.id
    GROUP BY U1.post_id
)
```

Prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you need to use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) instead of [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias).